# Fetching Webservice Data from Silverlight?

Tags: c#, http, web-services

So I've created my webservice (through HTTP), but now how do I fetch the data (XML data) via C#/.Net?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.95).aspx) and [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(VS.95).aspx) classes, here is a post that covers the basics:

http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/01/using-webclient-and-httpwebrequest.aspx